# What has happened to lifetime memberships in Clone Wars Adventures?

Tags: star-wars-clone-wars-adventures

At one time, you could buy a lifetime membership for Clone Wars Adventures for $50 (or so).  That option appears to not exist anymore.  Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the subscription options available on the "Become a Jedi Member" page...

[image]

This appears to be the case. Sometime back, the option for a lifetime subscription was dropped. There also was apparently a 12 month subscription option available in beta, which was also dropped.